# Java code convention clarification - directly coding numerical constants

Tags: java, conventions

In the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), section 10.3 it states:

> Numerical constants (literals) should not be coded directly, except for -1, 0, and 1, which can appear in a for loop as counter values.

What does it mean to 'code directly' numerical constants?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It refers to so called "magic numbers". Observe the following code:

```
float radians = 180/3.141;
```

versus

```
float degreesInRadians = myDegrees/Math.PI;
```

Which one is clearer?

Comment: If I use a single integer in a class 50 times is that not also a numerical constant? Or these refer only to mathematical constant?

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki They refer to every constants, mathematical constants are only a special case. But what do you mean "single integer 50 times"?

Comment: Well let say I have a special integer that has to be checked on multiple locations. (Some kind of limit maybe.) Should I than use a literal representation every time? Would it not be easier to use a constant so I can alter it at one place if I need to instead of how many times it is used?

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki Of course, if it's a constant it should be defined as a constant. Especially if you use it in several places and it might change in the future.

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki You should use a constant even if you only use it once, just to be able to give it a name.  And please don't put the number in the constant name (as I have seen).

Comment: Okay I realized my fault here, I just sort of misunderstood the problem. I'll keep it this way then thanks! :)

Comment: So what does it mean "except for -1, 0, and 1, which can appear in a for loop as counter values"?

Comment: @BugalugsNash It means that it's okay to write code such as "for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)". You'll learn to recognize where it's okay to use literal constants and where not to.

Comment: @Kayaman OK, just to get my head completely around it - so it's not ok to write for(int i=0;i < 2;i++) - because 2 is a numerical constant that is not 0, 1, or -1? Instead I should write something like for(int i=0;i < numberOfEyes;i++)?

Comment: @BugalugsNash There's no hard rules about this. If it's clear from the context what the 2 means here, and it won't change, it's not a terrible thing to write it directly. It's more clutter if you make a constant for every single number, just because you're trying to obey some "rule".

Answer (score 3):

It means when you use numbers in your code (other than -1, 0 and 1) that you use a constant to "label" it.

Ie instead of:

```
boolean pass = score >= 50;
```

Use this:

```
private static final int MINIMUM_PASS_SCORE = 50;

boolean pass = score >= MINIMUM_PASS_SCORE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means to use them without defining what they actually are. For example instead of stating:

```
public static double PI = 3.14; //<-- Clearly defines the meaning of this value.
```

you're just using the decimal value.

```
double a = Math.pow(3.14 * r, 2); // <-- Does not define the meaning of 3.14
```

This makes code harder to read, and therefore is an avoided practise.